# Real cropping a PDF file

Tags: itext, ghostscript

In [ghostscript-crop-pdf-not-correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051517/ghostscript-crop-pdf-not-correctly),I got a cropped PDF,but it's only seemingly cropped.The remaining content still exists in fact.

In [ghostscript-removes-content-outside-the-crop-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706976/ghostscript-removes-content-outside-the-crop-box) or
[how-to-truly-crop-a-pdf-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460427/how-to-truly-crop-a-pdf-file) or [pdf-real-cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717322/pdf-real-cropping) or [cropping-a-pdf-using-ghostscript-9-01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183479/cropping-a-pdf-using-ghostscript-9-01) or [itext-crop-out-a-part-of-pdf-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773942/itext-crop-out-a-part-of-pdf-file), no solution was found.May be a virtual PDF printer is the only way.

Use ghostscript or itext, Is there any way to clip a PDF file really.

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward (but perhaps not the most intelligent) way of solving your problem is to use `pdfSweep`.

`pdfSweep` is an `iText7` addon that allows you to redact (remove) content.

It allows you to remove content by:

- specifying a regular expression
- specifying a rectangle (or rectangles)

In your case, you could calculate the rectangles you want removed, and then apply `pdfSweep`.

If you then crop the remaining page, the content would really be gone.

More information (including code samples) can be found [here](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfSweep).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

What leads you to believe that the content is still present ?

Any object which is not at least partially contained within the page clip will not be forwarded on to the pdfwrite device by Ghostscript, so I'm doubtful that content is preserved.

Your original question related to cropping away white space, so that makes your example file less than useful in this case. You should post an example of the problem file, and the Ghostscript command line you have used.

Note that if you are trying to crop out an image then no, this won't do what you want. If any part of the image lies on the media, then the entire image will be included in the file. The pdfwrite device isn't equipped to extract sub-areas from images. This is true for all the PDF editors that I'm aware of.

Comment: As far as I know,.the iText 7 pdfSweep add-on clips images in such a way that the cropped pixels are removed.

Comment: Fair enough, its not code I'm familiar with. Ghostscript certainly doesn't do this.

Comment: open a croped pdf with adobe illustrator and select outline in menu view(ctrl+y),i can see the whole content.In addition the filesize is not smaller.

Comment: Here is the [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0uz9n3iug58mndc/MUT.06.05.10.07.57.pdf?dl=0).
I want get the left half,and the gs command is:`gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -o croped.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=298 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=841 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>>setpagedevice" -f MUT.06.05.10.07.57.pdf`

Comment: the screenshot: [img_croped](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ccgg7nx9s93lw9/croped.png?dl=0),
[img_with_outlines](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbg6srz1rv86u5v/result_with_outline.png?dl=0)

Comment: Yes, that's a PDF file whose contents are a single bitmap image. See answer and comments above. Another solution would be to extract the image form the PDF, crop out the bit you want using an image editor and make a new PDF. Or just use pdfSweep.